# Evercookie and formatting

Tags: privacy

Will formatting the system or deleting a virtual machine delete all evercookies that a site could have installed on the PC?

Answer (score 0):

At most, what you need to delete is your browser profile.

Most browsers have a command to clear private data. It happens sometimes that a new storage mechanism is introduced and the “clear private data” button isn't updated (for example, I seem to recall that in the early days of HTML5 local storage, there were browsers that implemented it but only offered a button to clear cookies, not local storage). If you don't trust your browser to erase private data, you may elect to delete the whole profile.

Deleting the whole system is not useful, at least if you've only done normal browsing and installed, and not accepted the installation of native code plugins that could access your computer beyond the browser's sandbox.

Note that deleting the whole system may conversely not be sufficient, if you've activated any kind of online synchronization (e.g. via a Google account). In this case you'd need to delete or stop using the online account.

Comment: But the firefox profile disappeare when the sistem is formatted. And when the sistem is reinstalled a new fresh profile will there be.  Maybe evercookies could be saved into the hardrive , but setting the broswer preference ''Localstorage.enabled'' to false, this should not happen.

''but you probably also need to delete flash cookies by running rm -rf ~/.macromedia ~/.adobe.''

This command deletes flash cookies? If i do not have flash installed i will have as well flash cookies? can not be cleaned with bleachbit?

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated, deleting your whole system is neither necessary nor sufficient.  Deleting your browser profile is a good start, but you probably also need to delete flash cookies by running `rm -rf ~/.macromedia ~/.adobe`.